# base_url in settings.php with mobile version

Tags: 7, caching

I've both www.example.com and m.example.com pointing to the same directory in Ubuntu and there was in the settings.php  with this line:

```
$base_url="www.example.com";
```

**I want to ask what will happen in this case in Drupal where sites are accessed as www. or the m. versions?**

In the hook_custom_theme I'm returing a mobile theme whenever the URL is starting with "m.".

I was getting some wierd mix up of mobile and the desktop versions.

I was not able to find any cid with "http://m." URLs in the cache_page mysql table. After I removed this $base_url now  both mobile and the desktop versions seem to be showing fine now and also cache_page table is having rows with cid with "http://m...".

**I'm not fully sure this but could $base_url cause this?**

Answer (score 2):

How is your `/sites` folder structure? You can create subdomain `m.example.com`, and implement the mobile version in there.

There are different approaches in implementing the subdomains in drupal. it may be *multisite and shared database* or *multisite with different databases* and *single code and different databases* .

what you are looking for is a shared database but different themes (multiple codes), Here is good [discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/2622) about this.